# Is there any r code to close all gaps in histogram using facet wrap with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I will like to take out  of all gaps in my plot even though, it is showing data but no bars.

Here is my code used:

```
length_2020 <- ggplot(data=help,aes(x=Length)) +
  geom_histogram    (aes(fill=Clay),    binwidth   =0.5,boundary=NULL)+
scale_y_continuous(name="Number of Length")+
facet_wrap(~ Clay, scales = "free")
```

[image: This is my histogram produce by this code]

Comment: hi what is rear of gaps?

Comment: How exactly do you want to get rid of them? Maybe try making your `binwidth=` larger? I'm not sure how you would close the gaps without breaking the axis.

Comment: I have a large data in the length field  and i first used this code scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq  but did not work .@StupidWolf I mean to take out gaps from my plot sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If I understant correctly, you want to remove the parts of the histogram that do not contain any numbers. However, this is not a good idea, since the x axis is continuous. In fact, it might be misleading. But if you want, you can `round()` your numbers and then make them discrete with `as.character()` or `as.factor()`. I don't think you should do it, though, so I hope I'm missing what you want.

```
length_2020 <- ggplot(data=help,aes(x=as.character(round(Length, 0)))) +
  geom_histogram    (aes(fill=Clay),    binwidth   =0.5,boundary=NULL)+
scale_y_continuous(name="Number of Length")+
facet_wrap(~ Clay, scales = "free")
```